# "Get going" VS. "Get gone"

Tags: difference, passive-voice, active-voice

I've looked it up for the meanings. What I was wondering now is the grammar part. Could anyone tell me how they differ in meanings relating to the present participle and past participle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "Get going"

For example "We need to get going".

This is a common, colloquial way of saying "We need to go".

You could imagine it means "We need to put ourselves into a state of 'going' ".

- "Get gone"

Slang, or an invented turn of phrase, which means "to leave". It's not standard written or spoken English, but makes enough sense that anyone would understand.

You could imagine it means "We need to put ourselves into a state of 'being gone' ".

From [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20gone):

> To get gone is to leave, bounce,
>   or get out of the area quickly.
>
> 1. Lets get gone before the cops come.
> 2. Time to get gone.